# Resample Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this:

```
                       date   emaslow
105857  2017-10-24 22:50:00  0.000037
105858  2017-10-24 22:55:00  0.000037
105859  2017-10-24 23:00:00  0.000037
```

It is a huge data set, this is only the `tail(3)` bit and the `date` and `emaslow` columns. I am trying to resample this a little bit so I get a smoother plot. But no matter what I do, I get the nasty:

```
TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but 
got an instance of 'RangeIndex'
```

I tried to `set` and `reset` the index with `df.reset_index()` and `df.set_index('date')`

But with no luck.

I am trying to get a smoother, version of the red plot. The blue one is wrong and it is just a place holder.

[image]

Comment: 1) Make sure the dtype's of the date column are datetime objects and not strings. 2) Make sure you are either doing df = df.set_index('date') or df.set_index('date', inplace=True). Just doing df.set_index('date') returns a new df, it doesn't update df automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for `resample`, you can change the `sum` to `mean`or whatever you need.

```
df.set_index('date').resample('10T').sum()
Out[502]: 
                      emaslow
date                         
2017-10-24 22:50:00  0.000074
2017-10-24 23:00:00  0.000037
```